# Checking if a Vector3 is being shown on the screen

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, camera

I was wondering whether or not there's a method to check if a Vector3 point in 3D space is being viewed by the camera, or perhaps to check whether or not the point is being shown on the screen.

Comment: 20 minutes ago you just asked a question you didn't even intend to engage in - no answer, commentaries or "that helped or not". And the question you're asking is pretty simple - but I don't see any effort you would already put in finding an answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, I have commented your answer on my first question when i saw it - I just had to wait 20 minutes until I was able to post the second question. Secondly, this question came from my thought to render the RenderTarget2D I use for the camera not each frame, but only when the mirror is seen by the player. I have thought of postion this, as you've said, simple question on my first one, but since it's a totally different question I've decided to post it as it's own.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just feed your view and projection matrices into a bounding frustum like this:

```
//class scope variables
BoundingFrustum boundingFrustum;

//in the init method
boundingFrustum = new BoundingFrustum();

//In the Update method or wherever you need to run a check check
boundingFrustum.Matrix = view * projection;

bool isPointInView = boundingFrustum.Contains(Vector3ToTest);
```